flycheck-grammalecte with Emacs 29.1
I am using Emacs 29.1 (build2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.33, cairo version 1.18.0
When evaluating the block
(with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
  (flycheck-grammalecte-setup))

I receive the error mentionned:
(wrong-type-argument stringp nil) string-to-number(nil) flycheck-grammalecte--path-flycheck-mode-map() flycheck-grammalecte-setup()
``
I have setup python3 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on an Itel Core i3-9100

Is it working on Emacs 29.x ?

